# file layout not found in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I have `MemberUpdate-3.1.0.jar` which consists
`fileLayout/rijan/output/Member_update_output_layout.csv`

and my `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` is

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=~/Projects/MemberUpdate/target/MemberUpdate-3.1.0.jar
```

However filenotfoundexception occurs with below Exception?. Is there anything setting I am missing to solve it

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
>   file:/home/rijan/Projects//target/MemberUpdate-3.1.0.jar!/fileLayout/rijan/output/Member_update_output_layout.csv
>   does not exist    at
>   com.rijan.das.scrub.loader.impl.BackupJob.copy(BackupJob.java:94)     at
>   com.rijan.das.scrub.loader.impl.BackupJob.copy(BackupJob.java:72)     at
>   com.rijan.das.scrub.loader.impl.BackupJob.processJob(BackupJob.java:52)
>     at com.rijan.das.scrub.loader.App.main(App.java:35)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
>   file:/home/rijan/Projects/MemberUpdate/target/MemberUpdate-3.1.0.jar!/fileLayout/rijan/output/Member_update_output_layout.csv
>   does not exist    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:511)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:724)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:402)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:337)    at
>   com.rijan.das.scrub.loader.impl.BackupJob.copy(BackupJob.java:92)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the full HDFS Path hdf://HOSTNAME:8020/fileLayout/rijan/output/Member_update_output_layout.csv

and see if it works.